# Is there any difference between jsx bootstrap and simple bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i am beginner in react js, using jsx bootstrap in react js, i have watched many videos in youtube some using jsx react and some using simple bootstrap with minimal classname change,that's why i got confused 
what have to use react bootstrap or simple bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

As it is documented in Bootstrap official website, "React-Bootstrap replaces the Bootstrap JavaScript. Each component has been built from scratch as a true React component, without unneeded dependencies like jQuery."

It is moreover stated that React-Bootstrap is a complete re-implementation of the Bootstrap components using React. It has no dependency on either bootstrap.js or jQuery. Hence, the dependencies on Jquery and Bootstrap.js are eliminated.

Methods and events using jQuery is done imperatively by directly manipulating the DOM. In contrast, React uses updates to the state to update the virtual DOM. In this way, React-Bootstrap provides a more reliable solution by incorporating Bootstrap functionality into React's virtual DOM.

If you are using React, React-Bootstrap would be a better option, as you will not need to add scripts such as jquery.js or bootstrap.js to your code. The React component model gives more control over form and function of each component.